# How to word wrap on UILabel that has infinite lines?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel in which the number of lines need to be set to 0 (infinite lines). But when it displays a single long word, it breaks the line by character, to form a second line. I tried to set Line breaking mode manually as such

```
cell.nameLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
cell.nameLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

But the app still breaks by character. How can I fix this?
Edit- I want the word font size to shrink.

Comment: What is the expected result? If a word can not fit then it will break by smaller unit which in this case is a character.

Comment: Added the expected result

Comment: AlthoughThisWebPageWillAutomaticallyBreakIntoLinesByWrappingWordsAsYouCanSeeInMyPreviousCommentItMayNotDoTheSameIfIWriteAWholeCommentAsASingleWordInThatCaseItWillBreakWhereverItSeesFitWrappingACharacter

Comment: Expected/hoped result is, to shrink the characters. To a minimum font size. The priority should be, to not break the word. If the word breaks even after the minimum font size, they can break on character.

Comment: Wrapping word does not automatically shrink words. Automatic shrinking is done per label. I am not sure if a tool exists that suits your needs but I would create a new question about it if you have already checked the web.

Comment: I understand that Wrapping doesn't shrink the word. I was hoping, adjustsFontSizeToWidth would do it.

Comment: Check out the update on my answer. The results look pretty good actually...

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting font size is unfortunately done per label, not per line. Wrapping does not effect it. So the result you are seeing is expected. You could split your string manually into multiple labels maybe putting them into stack view to get desired result.

What I tried was:

```
private func layoutText(text: String, onStackView stackView: UIStackView) {
    var words: [String] = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)

    var currentLineWords: [String] = [String]()
    var currentLabel: UILabel!

    func newLabel() -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel(frame: stackView.bounds)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        return label
    }

    while words.count > 0 {
        if currentLineWords.count == 0 {
            currentLabel = newLabel()
            currentLineWords.append(words.removeFirst())
        } else {
            let newText = currentLineWords.joined(separator: " ") + " " + words[0]
            currentLabel.text = newText
            currentLabel.sizeToFit()

            if currentLabel.bounds.width > stackView.bounds.width {
                // Break line
                currentLabel.text = currentLineWords.joined(separator: " ")
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(currentLabel)
                currentLabel = nil
                currentLineWords = [String]()
            } else {
                // All good
                currentLineWords.append(words.removeFirst())
            }
        }
    }

    if currentLineWords.count > 0 {
        currentLabel.text = currentLineWords.joined(separator: " ")
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(currentLabel)
    }
}
```

This works pretty neatly but:

- When word is too long to fit in a line even when shrunk it will show "..." at the end
- Shrunk line still has the same height instead of having it reduced
- We are only handling whitespaces and inserting back spaces

The first 2 would probably both be solved by having manual `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. Basically keep reducing font size until it fits or until a certain size. If "certain size" scenario is hit then simply use multiline on a label (will break by characters).

The last one just need some extra effort.

I would still not implement this for multiple reasons one of them being that it looks ugly but is still interesting.

**Custom font size adjustment:**

To have custom font adjustment and all the logic there is only a change when a new lien is created:

```
            if currentLineWords.count == 0 {
                currentLabel = newLabel()
                currentLineWords.append(words.removeFirst())

                currentLabel.text = currentLineWords.joined(separator: " ")
                currentLabel.sizeToFit()

                if currentLabel.bounds.width > stackView.bounds.width {
                    currentLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false

                    let originalFontSize: CGFloat = currentLabel.font.pointSize
                    var currentFontSize: CGFloat = originalFontSize
                    let minimalFontSize: CGFloat = currentLabel.minimumScaleFactor > 0.0 ? currentLabel.font.pointSize * currentLabel.minimumScaleFactor : originalFontSize

                    while currentLabel.bounds.width > stackView.bounds.width {
                        currentFontSize -= 1.0
                        if currentFontSize < minimalFontSize {
                            currentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                            currentLabel.font = UIFont(name: currentLabel.font.fontName, size: originalFontSize)
                            break // Could not shrink it even further. USe multiline
                        }
                        currentLabel.font = UIFont(name: currentLabel.font.fontName, size: currentFontSize)
                        currentLabel.sizeToFit()
                    }

                    // Break line
                    stackView.addArrangedSubview(currentLabel)
                    currentLabel = nil
                    currentLineWords = [String]()
                }
            }
```

This looks usable now. My result:

[image]